# My Custom Text For Each Few Hours With JavaScript Isn't Working

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to get a custom greeting depending on the user's calendar and clock.  It used to work great, but I just copy pasted from some old code for my new site and it has ended up not displaying at all.  Here's what I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
var time=d.getHours();
var elem=document.getElementById('sunMoon')

if (time>=6 && time<=12)
{
 elem.textContent = "testing";
}
if (time > 13 && time < 17)
  {
  elem.textContent = "Good afternoon!";
  }
if (time > 18 && time < 24)
  {
  elem.textContent = "Good evening!";
  }
if (time > 0 && time < 5)
  {
  elem.textContent = "Have a nice night!"
  }
</script>
```

Ok, so suggestions followed, but I only get the same result-nothing.  The above code has been edited to reflect the new formatting.

Comment: Check your console. Are there any errors? Also, what’s in the surrounding page?

Comment: Not the reason it doesn't work, but those nested `if` statements without `{}` are kind of confusing, especially with no indentation. Why not `if (time > 12 && time < 18)` instead of `if (time > 12) if (time < 18)`? (Incidentally, when I ran your code it wrote "testing", which was correct given that it is 10:18am here.)

Comment: I check the console, I just use notepad, I didn't notice any typos.  What do you suggest I do about the if statements?

Comment: What else is on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an element with an ID of `sunMoon`, but never using it. Instead, your code uses `document.write`. If you meant to put the text in that element, you should replace

```
document.write("...")
```

with

```
elem.textContent = "..."
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/82BTA/).

I replaced `document.write` with `alert`, so maybe that's causing you problems? Try using `alert` to see some feedback or looking at your console for debugging messages.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you don't have the "sunMoon" id element anymore in your markup.
Try this and see that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/82BTA/7/

HTML

```
<p><span id="sunMoon"></span>, user2757975.</p>
```

JS

```
var d=new Date();
var time=d.getHours();
var elem=document.getElementById('sunMoon')

if (time > 5 && time <= 12)
{
 elem.textContent = "Good Morning!";
}
if (time > 12 && time <= 18)
  {
  elem.textContent = "Good afternoon!";
  }
if (time > 18 && time <= 24)
  {
  elem.textContent = "Good evening!";
  }
if (time > 0 && time <= 5)
  {
  elem.textContent = "Have a nice night!"
  }
```

Comment: Now it's working (:P i'm a dork, can't believe I forgot that), but it's appearing as a popup instead of just plain text.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Then you have "alert" in your code. Remove any "alert" and replace them with "elem.textContent". A full code would be best if you want more suggestions.